# Why does a function that loads a ListView take significantly longer to run when called from the app compared to at start-up?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I am using a ListView in a Forms App which takes significantly longer to load the ListView with content if the load function is called from a button click (Reload ListView) compared to being called at start-up in the Form() function – see code.

The Forms app has a ListView (listView1) with three columns, a ‘Clear ListView’ button (button2) to clear the contents of the ListView, and a ‘Reload ListView’ button (button1) to call the same LoadListViewItems() function that is called at start-up. The Form also includes a TextBox (textBox1) to displaying the results (number of items loaded, time taken to load).

When I talk about it being slower, based upon the tests performed it is about 200x slower.

On my laptop it takes between 3 to 6 ms to load the ListView at start-up compared 953 to 1044 ms when clicking the Reload button following the ListView being cleared ‘Clear ListViw’ button.

I’ve tried disabling the redraw until the ListView has loaded by uncommenting out:

```
SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, false, 0);
SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, true, 0);
this.Refresh();
```

This has no effect on the time taken to load at start-up but results in a slightly faster time using the Load button: 727 to 769 ms.

If I comment out:

```
lvwColumnSorter = new ListViewColumnSorter();
this.listView1.ListViewItemSorter = lvwColumnSorter;
```

in the InitializeListView1() function which disables the column sort, it has no effect on the start-up load time but does improve the Reload button time: 180 to 203 ms. It is therefore clear that this is having an effect.

My question is, why does the ListView load significantly quicker at start-up compared to loading the ListView with the same using a button on the Forms app, and how can I make it load faster from the Forms apps whilst retaining the column sort functionality?

```
Form1.cs

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace FormsAppListView
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public bool MultiSelect { get; set; }
        private ListViewColumnSorter lvwColumnSorter;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 wMsg, bool wParam, Int32 lParam);
        private const int WM_SETREDRAW = 11;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            InitializeListView1();

            LoadListViewItems();
        }

        // This method adds two columns to the ListView, setting the Text 
        // and TextAlign, and Width properties of each ColumnHeader.  The 
        // HeaderStyle property is set to NonClickable since the ColumnClick 
        // event is not handled.  Finally the method adds ListViewItems and 
        // SubItems to each column.
        private void InitializeListView1()
        {
            // Create an instance of a ListView column sorter and assign it
            // to the ListView control.
            lvwColumnSorter = new ListViewColumnSorter();
            this.listView1.ListViewItemSorter = lvwColumnSorter;
            this.listView1.Name = "ListView1";
            this.listView1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.listView1.View = System.Windows.Forms.View.Details;
            this.listView1.MultiSelect = true;
            this.listView1.HideSelection = false;
            this.listView1.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.Clickable;
            this.listView1.GridLines = true;
            this.Controls.Add(listView1);
        }

        private void ListView1_ColumnClick(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
        {
            // Determine if clicked column is already the column that is being sorted.
            if (e.Column == lvwColumnSorter.SortColumn)
            {
                // Reverse the current sort direction for this column.
                if (lvwColumnSorter.Order == SortOrder.Ascending)
                {
                    lvwColumnSorter.Order = SortOrder.Descending;
                }
                else
                {
                    lvwColumnSorter.Order = SortOrder.Ascending;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Set the column number that is to be sorted; default to ascending.
                lvwColumnSorter.SortColumn = e.Column;
                lvwColumnSorter.Order = SortOrder.Ascending;
            }

            // Perform the sort with these new sort options.
            this.listView1.Sort();
        }

        private void LoadListViewItems()
        {
            try
            {
                int i = 0;

                //SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, false, 0);

                long start_ms = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;

                for (i = 0; i < 1001; i++)
                {
                    string col1 = "item-" + i;
                    string col2 = "sub-item-" + i + "a";
                    string col3 = "sub-item-" + i + "b";

                    ListViewItem listItem = new ListViewItem(col1);
                    listItem.SubItems.Add(col2);
                    listItem.SubItems.Add(col3);
                    listView1.Items.Add(listItem);

                }
                textBox1.Text = "items added = " + i + Environment.NewLine;

                long end_ms = DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
                textBox1.Text += "Time taken to add = " + (end_ms - start_ms) + " ms" + Environment.NewLine;

                //SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, true, 0);
                //this.Refresh();
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
                string errorMessage = "Error: " + error.Message + Environment.NewLine;
                MessageBox.Show(errorMessage);
                return;
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.Items.Clear();                // Clear current ListView
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadListViewItems();
        }
    }
}


Class1.cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows.Forms;

/// <summary>
/// This class is an implementation of the 'IComparer' interface.
/// </summary>
public class ListViewColumnSorter : IComparer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies the column to be sorted
    /// </summary>
    private int ColumnToSort;

    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies the order in which to sort (i.e. 'Ascending').
    /// </summary>
    private SortOrder OrderOfSort;

    /// <summary>
    /// Case insensitive comparer object
    /// </summary>
    private CaseInsensitiveComparer ObjectCompare;

    /// <summary>
    /// Class constructor. Initializes various elements
    /// </summary>
    public ListViewColumnSorter()
    {
        // Initialize the column to '0'
        ColumnToSort = 0;

        // Initialize the sort order to 'none'
        OrderOfSort = SortOrder.None;

        // Initialize the CaseInsensitiveComparer object
        ObjectCompare = new CaseInsensitiveComparer();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is inherited from the IComparer interface. It compares the two objects passed using a case insensitive comparison.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="x">First object to be compared</param>
    /// <param name="y">Second object to be compared</param>
    /// <returns>The result of the comparison. "0" if equal, negative if 'x' is less than 'y' and positive if 'x' is greater than 'y'</returns>
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        int compareResult;
        ListViewItem listviewX, listviewY;

        // Cast the objects to be compared to ListViewItem objects
        listviewX = (ListViewItem)x;
        listviewY = (ListViewItem)y;

        string temp = listviewX.ListView.Columns[ColumnToSort].Tag.ToString();

        // Compare the two items
        if (temp == "numeric")
        {
            compareResult = ObjectCompare.Compare(int.Parse(listviewX.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text), int.Parse(listviewY.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text));
        }
        else
        {
            compareResult = ObjectCompare.Compare(listviewX.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text, listviewY.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text);
        }

        // Calculate correct return value based on object comparison
        if (OrderOfSort == SortOrder.Ascending)
        {
            // Ascending sort is selected, return normal result of compare operation
            return compareResult;
        }
        else if (OrderOfSort == SortOrder.Descending)
        {
            // Descending sort is selected, return negative result of compare operation
            return (-compareResult);
        }
        else
        {
            // Return '0' to indicate they are equal
            return 0;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the number of the column to which to apply the sorting operation (Defaults to '0').
    /// </summary>
    public int SortColumn
    {
        set
        {
            ColumnToSort = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return ColumnToSort;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the order of sorting to apply (for example, 'Ascending' or 'Descending').
    /// </summary>
    public SortOrder Order
    {
        set
        {
            OrderOfSort = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return OrderOfSort;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably better fit for [codereview.se]

Comment: BTW, you don't need to PInvoke `WM_SETREDRAW`, you can use the managed `BeginUpdate()` / `EndUpdate()` methods: these do the same exact thing (note: you must always call both these methods, since there's an internal counter that keeps track of the calls - use a try/finally block) These methods all check whether the Control's handle has been created -> the initial calls to fill the ListView are made when the Control's Handle is not created yet - I don't see you subscribing to any events. -- Use a StopWatch to measure the elapsed time

Comment: BTW2, the ListView is not the only Control that provides `BeginUpdate()` / `EndUpdate()` methods. Other classes use `SuspendLayout()` / `ResumeLayout()`. When these are present, you should called them while performing updates.

Comment: @Charlieface OK, haven't used Code Review before and only the second time I have posted a question here. If I post there, do you suggest I delete this post here?

Comment: Yes, or you could raise a flag and get a mod to migrate it. Make sure it fits according to [codereview.se]'s rules

Comment: @Jim Thanks for suggestions. I tried BeginUpdate() / EndUpdate() before trying WM_SETREDRAW. I think speed increase was similar. Not sure I’ve tried SuspendLayout() / ResumeLayout() so will do more tests. I’ve used try/catch before, but not a try/finally block. So the initial LoadListViewItems() call being executed extremely quickly is because the Control’s Handle has not been created, but it has when I run the same by clicking on the app button. I’ll use StopWatch to replace my current code. Not sure I understand what you mean by “I don’t see you subscribing to any events”? Many thanks.

Comment: Progress:
~950 ms without steps to speed up
~950 ms this.SuspendLayout() – doesn’t seem to do anything
~730 ms SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_SETREDRAW, false, 0)
~560 ms listView1.BeginUpdate()
~45 ms listView1.BeginUpdate() and //lvwColumnSorter = new ListViewColumnSorter();
Can I somehow disable the column sorter whilst loading then enable after loading?

Comment: `SuspendLayout()` is applied to a Form here, hence it's irrelevant: you're not changing the layout of the Form itself. -- As mentioned, you don't need WM_SETREDRAW, since `BeginUpdate()` already sends that message (with priority). Remember that you MUST call `EndUpdate()` after. --  Extracting text from subitems and parsing can be vexing. BTW,  you're not checking for `null` or `empty` beforehand.

Comment: The try/finally block is simply `try { [ListView].BeginUpdate(); // do stuff } finally { [ListView].EndUpdate(); }`. That's what a `using` statement does -- A `catch` block is not mandatory (the `try` block can also be empty, when needed: the code in the `finally` block is always executed, even when an exception is thrown in the meantime).

Comment: @Jimi Thanks for your input. I have a solution which makes the loading of the ListView from button click 30 times faster than it was whilst still retaining the column sort function. Instead of adding each item to the ListView individually using “listView1.Items.Add(listItem);”, I add the items to a ListView array instead, and add the array to the ListView at the end using “listView1.Items.AddRange(items);”. This takes ~35 ms compared to ~950 ms.
My only issue now is deciding on the size of the array to use as my current application reads in the items from a file.

Comment: @Jimi I will add the try/finally as you suggest but am wondering how this helps if an exception is thrown in the try? I can see that the listView1.EndUpdate(); will execute, but from there will it return to the main program? I suppose I can give it a try as if my array size is wrong it throws an error!

Comment: It helps because the code in the `finally` block is executed no matter what. It's important because, as mentioned, a call to `BeginUpdate()` must have an `EndUpdate()` counterpart call, otherwise the internal counter (used to make sure the calls are paired) may cause the code to skip the `BeginUpdate()` call (the next time you use it with the same Control) -- An exception thrown in the `try` block may prevent the call to `EndUpdate()` from being executed.

Comment: @Jimi Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for the explanation. I've just implemented my findings from this posting into the actual application code and what was taking 23 seconds now completes in just over half second. Your help getting there much appreciated, many thanks.